# Jest Setup with Next.js fails after it seems to add a react import to index.test.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js

Hi I have been stewing over this for the last couple of days. I realise this is a common error with various solutions.

I have the dreaded:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
/__tests__/index.test.js:16
    import React from "react";
    ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)
```

I have read a few posts and the docs in next and jest.
package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "some-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.3",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.2",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.1",
    "eslint": "8.16.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.6",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "description": "This is a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project bootstrapped with [`create-next-app`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/create-next-app).",
  "main": "jest.config.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": { 
  },
}
```

index.test.js:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Home from '../pages/index'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import React from "react";

describe('Home', () => {
  it('renders a h', () => {
    render(<Home />)

    const link = screen.getByRole('link', {
      name: "Library",
    })

    expect(link).toHaveAttribute('href', '/storage-area')
  })
});
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: true,
  // on node 14.x coverage provider v8 offers good speed and more or less good report
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!**/*.d.ts',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!<rootDir>/out/**',
    '!<rootDir>/.next/**',
    '!<rootDir>/*.config.js',
    '!<rootDir>/coverage/**',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle CSS imports (with CSS modules)
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#mocking-css-modules
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',

    // Handle CSS imports (without CSS modules)
    '^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',

    // Handle image imports
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets
    '^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|avif|ico|bmp|svg)$/i': `<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js`,

    // Handle module aliases
    '^@/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components/$1',
  },
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/.next/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    // Use babel-jest to transpile tests with the next/babel preset
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['next/babel', '@babel/preset-react',"@babel/preset-env" ]}],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
  ],
}
```

As I mentioned in the title the it seems that the error message suggests that the import is added by Next.js to the end of the index.test.js.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem due to the **tests** folder being nested in the directory above the root directory of the project. By the time I figured this out I had manipulated the jest.config.js transform: presets array property to contain imports that it didn't require in the standard jest/next setup.